# Manifest V3 extension: background's ServiceWorker does not unload after sending message to popup

Tags: javascript, service-worker, sendmessage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

With manifest V3, the background's Service Worker will unload (being inactive) after idling for 30 seconds. When I send a runtime message from popup to background without any further actions, after 30 seconds, the background's Service Worker is unloaded like usual. But when I send a runtime message from background to popup, it is not unloaded when idling anymore until it is forcefully unloaded by 5 minutes.

After it is forcefully unloaded by 5 minutes cap, when the popup is triggered again, message is not successfully passed anymore.

Here are the test codes (no special permissions):
manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test sw-pp msg",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

popup.js

```
const lblStatus = document.getElementById('lblStatus');

// send test message from popup to background -> OK
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('to-background', (res) => {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        lblStatus.textContent = 'Error';
    } else {
        lblStatus.textContent = 'OK';
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg == 'to-popup') {
        lblStatus.textContent = 'Message from background to popup';
        sendResponse(1);
    }
});
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="lblStatus" style="padding: 2em; font-size: 2em;"></div>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (msg == 'to-background') {
    console.log('Message from popup to background');
    sendResponse(1);

    /* Test sending message from background to popup
    - The first time the message is sent, the background's service worker may still be unloaded like usual
    - The second,... time the message is sent, the background's service worker is not unloaded anymore.
    - Without below code, the background's service worker is unloaded like usual
    */
    setTimeout(() => {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage('to-popup', (res) => {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.log('ERR');
        } else {
          console.log('OK');
        }
      });
    }, 2000);
  }
});
```

So I wonder what is the correct way to send message from background to popup (or options,...) in Manifest V3 extension?

Comment: It's a bug. The code is entirely correct and should work. As a workaround, try using port-based messaging.

Comment: I have tried creating a port, but the bug still happens.

Comment: Try Chrome Canary (or a [snapshot](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/) for your OS) and if it's bugged as well, report it on https://crbug.com.

Comment: I have just filled a bug report to crbug.com, hopefully there's a solution for this. [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1315117)

Comment: @trihai3012 I tried your code and it prints nothing to me in popup and from background.js it is printing `ERR`

Comment: I think it should be fine as long as the popup remains opened. You can change the console.log('ERR') to console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message) to see the actual error message.